# Comparing Two Data Frames in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. I have to compare the two data frames and get the position of the unmatched data using python.

Note:
The First column will always not be unique.

Data Frame 1:

```
   0         1   2                          3        4
0  1     Dhoni  24  Kota                       60000.0
1  2     Raina  90  Delhi                      41500.0
2  3     Kholi  67  Ahmedabad                  20000.0
3  4    Ashwin  45  Bhopal                      8500.0
4  5    Watson  64  Mumbai                      6500.0
5  6  KL Rahul  19  Indore                      4500.0
6  7    Hardik  24  Bengaluru                   1000.0
```

Data Frame 2

```
   0         1   2                          3        4
0  3     Kholi  67  Ahmedabad                  20000.0
1  7    Hardik  24  Bengaluru                   1000.0
2  4    Ashwin  45  Bhopal                      8500.0
3  2     Raina  90  Delhi                      41500.0
4  6  KL Rahul  19  Chennai                    4500.0
5  1     Dhoni  24  Kota                       60000.0
6  5    Watson  64  Mumbai                      6500.0
```

I expect the output of `(3,5)-(Indore - Chennai)`.

Comment: I edited the dataframes for you, they were fine, now you add pictures..

Comment: Please roll back your latest edit... (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit. I need the code ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':['Dhoni','Raina','KL Rahul'],'B':[24,90,67],'C':['Kota','Delhi','Indore'],'D':[6000.0,41500.0,4500.0]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':['Dhoni','Raina','KL Rahul'],'B':[24,90,67],'C':['Kota','Delhi','Chennai'],'D':[6000.0,41500.0,4500.0]})

df1['df']='df1'
df2['df']='df2'
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B','C','D'],keep=False)

print(df)
          A   B        C       D   df
2  KL Rahul  67   Indore  4500.0  df1
2  KL Rahul  67  Chennai  4500.0  df2
```

I have added df column to show, from which df difference comes from

Comment: Can you help me in sorting the output data by column label '0'?

Comment: `df2=df2.sort_values(by=['0'])`

Comment: Hey, I am getting the unmatched rows also. I will have to show the users the unmatched row and their data frames as well.